# How to create a unique identifier for 100000 with 5 characters?

Tags: r

I have 100,000 individuals
Using a combination of upper case letters, lower case letters and numbers, I want to create
a five-character ID for each individual. I should not have any duplicates.
How can I do this? I have tried the code below but I have 4 duplicates.

What is the number of possible unique combinations to create a 5 character ID with `"letters"`, `"LETTERS"` and `"0:9"`?

```
set.seed(0)
    
    mydata<-data.frame(
      ID=rep(NA,10^5),
      Poids=rnorm(n=10^5,mean = 65,sd=5)
    )
    
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
      
      mydata$ID[i]<-c(
        paste(sample(c(0:9,LETTERS,letters),replace = F,size = 1),             
              sample(c(0:9,LETTERS,letters),replace = F,size = 1),  
              sample(c(0:9,LETTERS,letters),replace = F,size = 1),               
              sample(c(0:9,LETTERS,letters),replace = F,size = 1),
              sample(c(0:9,LETTERS,letters),replace = F,size = 1),sep = "")
      )       
    }
    
    
    table(duplicated(mydata$ID))

FALSE  TRUE 
99996     4
```

Comment: `(length(letters) + length(LETTERS) + length(0:9))^5` is 91,6132,832. You have plenty of space left.

Comment: @AllanCameron it shoud be less than `(length(letters) + length(LETTERS) + length(0:9))^5` in my case. For example if I take ("A" ,"a", and "1"). I want to have all possible combination of two characters, I do not have 3^2 possibilities. I can only have Aa A1, a1, aA, 1A,1a. The number of characters of the combination should not ba random, but the same.

Comment: Do you not also have AA, aa, and 11? This would be 9, which would indeed be 3^2. If you don't want repeated characters in any ID, you still have 62 * 61 * 60 * 59 * 58 which is over 77 million possibilities

Comment: `stringi` has a function for generating random strings that is fast.  You could comfortably oversample and deduplicate - `unique(stringi::stri_rand_strings(110000, 5, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"))[1:100000]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(length(letters) + length(LETTERS) + length(0:9))^5` is 91,6132,832, so there is plenty of space to avoid clashes.

In fact, we can use this number to help generate our sample. We draw 100,000 integers out of 91,6132,832 without replacement and interpret each number as its unique string of characters using a bit of modular math and indexing. This can all be done in a single pass:

```r
space <- c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9)

set.seed(0)

samps <- sample(length(space)^5, 10^5)

m <- matrix("", nrow = 10^5, ncol = 5)

for(i in seq(ncol(m))) {
  m[,i] <- space[(samps %% length(space)) + 1]
  samps <- samps %/% length(space)
}

ID <- apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

We can see this fulfils our requirements:

```r
head(ID)
#> [1] "vpdnq" "rK0ej" "ofE9t" "PqLIr" "6G6tu" "Vhc7R"

length(ID)
#> [1] 100000

length(unique(ID))
#> [1] 100000
```

The whole thing takes less than a second on my modest machine:

```r
   user  system elapsed 
   0.72    0.00    0.74
```

---

**Update**

It occurs to me that it is possible to give 100,000 people a unique ID using only 16 characters, i.e. 0-9 and a-f, with code that is much quicker and simpler than above:

```r
set.seed(0)
ID <- as.hexmode(sample(16^5, 10^5))
head(ID)
#> [1] "d43f9" "392a7" "033a2" "cf1d7" "aa10e" "134bb"

length(unique(ID))
#> [1] 100000
```

Which takes less than 10 milliseconds.

<sup>Created on 2022-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks, but I just realized that you could do `as.hexmode(sample(16^5, 10^5))`, which takes less than 10 milliseconds and uses only 16 characters.

Comment: That's really a nice proposal using `as.hexmode` if OP's expected output is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below (given `N <- 1e5` and `k <- 5`):

```
n <- ceiling(N^(1 / k))
S <- sample(c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9), n)
ID <- head(do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(S), k))),N)
```

where

- `n` gives a subset of the whole space that supports all unique combinations up to given number `N`, e.g., `N <- 100000`
- `S` denotes a sub-space from which we draw the alphabets or digits
- `expand.grid` gives all combinations

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need randomness, the highly performant `arrangements` package can help by iterating over the permutations in order, not generating any more than are needed:

```
library(arrangements)

x = c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9)
ix = ipermutations(x = x, k = 5)

ind = ix$getnext(d = nrow(mydata))
mydata$ID = apply(ind, MAR = 1, FUN = \(i) paste(x[i], collapse = ""))

rbind(head(mydata), tail(mydata))
#           ID    Poids
# 1      abcde 64.46278
# 2      abcdf 62.00053
# 3      abcdg 75.71787
# 4      abcdh 67.73765
# 5      abcdi 66.45402
# 6      abcdj 66.85561
# 99995  abFpe 56.20545
# 99996  abFpf 64.14443
# 99997  abFpg 70.70191
# 99998  abFph 66.83226
# 99999  abFpi 65.22835
# 100000 abFpj 56.28880
```

This is quite fast:

```
  user  system elapsed 
  0.194   0.001   0.203
```